# How to remove custom fields from “WooCommerce Thankyou Order” email?

Tags: wordpress, hook-woocommerce

I have added custom fields to my product. I don't want to display those into "WooCommerce Thankyou Order" email. Please, can someone tell me, how to hide the custom fields?

> For ex: I want to hide the details that are highlighted email template

[image: Thankyou mail]

Answer (score -1):

Go **WooCommerce** in the wordpress Dashboard, click on **Email** tab. At the end you have **Email Template**.

In order to override the default email template edit `woocommerce/templates/emails/customer-process-proshop/woocommerce/emails/customer-processing-order.php`

At least that's WooCommerce instructions says. I do not have a wordpress with commerece to test or check that file but I suppose in there you could decide what information is actually sent to the customer.

Comment: Thank you for information. But this information is sent from my custom plugin. So I need to hide these details from my plugin itself